# How to check internet with LiveData in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

In my application I want check internet connection and for this I want use LiveData.
I write below codes, but after build project show me error!
I used Hilt for dependency injection.

CheckConnection class :

```
class CheckConnection @Inject constructor(private val cm: ConnectivityManager) : LiveData<Boolean>() {

    constructor(application: Application) : this(
        application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)
                as ConnectivityManager
    )

    private val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            postValue(true)
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            postValue(false)
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        val request = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        cm.registerNetworkCallback(request.build(), networkCallback)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        cm.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
    }

}
```

With below codes I initialize this in Fragment.

```
@Inject
lateinit var connection : CheckConnection
```

After build project show me below error :

```
D:\Projects\Android\MyTest\KotlinArchitectureExamples\mvvm\build\generated\hilt\component_sources\debug\com\app\mvvm\MyApp_HiltComponents.java:135: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.net.ConnectivityManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MyApp_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      android.net.ConnectivityManager is injected at
          com\app.mvvm.food.utils.CheckConnection(cm, �)
      com\app.mvvm.food.utils.CheckConnection is injected at
          com\app.mvvm.food.ui.list.FoodsListFragment.connection
      com\app.mvvm.food.ui.list.FoodsListFragment is injected at
          com\app.mvvm.food.ui.list.FoodsListFragment_GeneratedInjector.injectFoodsListFragment(com\app.mvvm.food.ui.list.FoodsListFragment) [com\app.mvvm.MyApp_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com\app.mvvm.MyApp_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com\app.mvvm.MyApp_HiltComponents.ActivityC ? com\app.mvvm.MyApp_HiltComponents.FragmentC]
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says:

> [Dagger/MissingBinding] android.net.ConnectivityManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.

It means that Dagger doesn't know to get an instance of `ConnectivityManager`, which is required in your `CheckConnection`.

Since you don't own `ConnectivityManager`, you need to provide it through `@Provides`. So in your Dagger/Hilt module you should add something like:

```
@Provides
fun provideConnectivityManager(@ApplicationContext context: Context) =
    context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
```

This way `ConnectivityManager` is added to the dependency graph and can be injected where it's requested.